# Find string in file, replace everything after "="?

Tags: file, scala, io, replace

I would like to read a file, find some strings and replace everything that is after the symbol "=" in this line.

Lets say I have a textfile like this:

```
name=whatever
age=150
id.from.system=10298092_42_42

path=D:\name\somewhere
whatever_A= WHATEVER
```

Lets say I want to change path. At first I have to find the string "path" and then replace everything after "=" somehow. Any ideas? I know I could easily read the file line by line something like this:

```
val source = io.Source.fromFile("C:/myfile.txt)
val lines = source.mkString
source.close()
```

But this is maybe not the best idea, because its not that performant to read the whole file (maybe the file got 10000000 lines, and the string is already at line 2, but my program would read the whole file. That would be unnecessary).

And there is maybe another problem: if Im searching for specific strings, like here for "name" but these strings are there several times. I want to make sure that its only valid is after the string there is an "=". Maybe I could search always for something with an "=" at the end, that could solve the problem. But I have no idea how to write this in a nice scala code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your C:/myfile.txt contains the line `path=D:\name\somewhere`, you can replace `D:\name\somewhere` with the following code:

```
val lines = fromString("path=D:\\name\\somewhere").getLines // use fromFile here 
for { in <- lines
      out <- if (in startsWith("path=")) "path=D:\\my\\path" else in
} yield out
```

This example will return the string

```
path=D:\my\path
```

You would need to use `fromFile` to get the lines and write the lines out to a new file.

Here's another approach that accomplishes the same thing:

```
val lines = fromString("path=D:\\name\\somewhere").getLines
lines.map(in => if (in startsWith("path=")) "path=D:\\my\\path" else in)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an iterator to only iterate until you find the line you're looking for.

```
val source = io.Source.fromFile("somePath").getLines
val line = source.find(_.startsWith("path="))
```

line will contain the first line that starts with "path=".

Comment: But this is not an iterator right? And I have no idea how to replace the line with my new string

Comment: The .getLines method will get you an iterator and .find method will iterate on the iterator until the first match of _.startsWith("path=")

Regarding the replacing of the string, are you trying to write the file with the replaced value?

Comment: Ah now I understand thank you. And yes I would like to write into this file and replace the value that is after the '='. So if I find "path=" I would like to replace the "D:\name\somewhere" value (or lets say, everything that is behind the '=' in this line) with my own string.

Comment: You have to write the entire file, or at least the parts after the line you replaced since your newly replaced line could be longer than the previous line, which will overwrite the data after the line you replaced.